# error in android application class but app is working fine

Tags: android, android-studio, android-sdk-2.3, android-sdk-manager, android-gradle-3.0

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CtGS7.png)

Application class looks like this but app working fine ..
why is this showing error ?

Comment: please don't post your code as an image. see https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Answer (score 0):

The file you've opened is [Application](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application)

This is not a part of your app. You can refer to it as API documentation of how/when to use a particular class and see what it actually does.

To distinguish you can look at the top right corner of the editor showing "Reader Mode".